# how to read a file from folder without giving filename , in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsfilemanager, file-handling

I am moving a file to a folder ( file is stored in other folder), I am moving it by giving the file name, but I want to move all files, which r stored in a folder to some other folder.
How can I do this ?
Thanks in advance.

```
-(void)MoveFilesToMyInBoxFolder:(NSString *)destfileName

{

NSString* fullPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[destfileName stringByDeletingPathExtension]  ofType:@"xml"];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

if (!documentsDirectory) {
    NSLog(@"ERROR:Documents directory not found!");
    return;
}
```

i am calling this method like

```
[self MoveFilesToMyInBoxFolder:@"QS-H02032011100717AM1.xml"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `contentsOfDirectoryAtPath` method of `NSFileManager` you can get an array of file names of all items within a directory. You can iterate through this array and move each item.